Should we take Fatwa from Chatgpt or other AI-bots?
I have some friends who take fatwas from chatgpt and i tried to tell them that it is wrong. I told them that chatgpt doesn't gave the knowledge on fiqh to give Fatawas but they told me ,that chatgpt can take answers from websites.
Please tell me if it is right to take fatwas from any AI-bot. jazakAllahu Khayran.

Of course you can not use AI to give fatwa for the following reasons:

AI bots do not have comprehensive knowledge of islamic sources as most are not available online
Alot of online sources themselves which the AI bots form their knowledge from are polluted by wrong answers and islamaphobia
AI bots can make mistakes as they are


A Muslim will be called to account only from the Quran.  In addition, hadiths are in a way a user manual of the Quran.  There are certain conditions to interpret both.  Simply put, which are mutawatir hadiths? What are the dates of revelation of the verses? Did it come for a specific event or is it a general verse?  What is said before and after the verse?  You are entirely responsible for the information that comes externally, other than directly from the Quran and hadiths.  So, when you migrate to the afterlife and are asked why you made this mistake, you cannot say "but ChatGTP told me so".  Because Muslims are also responsible for researching and learning and will be held accountable.
In order to draw conclusions from a verse, the entire sura must be read and examined.  We don't know if ChatGTP does this.
One of the most important things that distinguishes the Quran from others is that not a single word has changed since 1400 years.  However, you cannot know or be sure that an artificial intelligence software will interpret or change this differently depending on the conditions of the time.
